# Regex, ¿Cómo negar (no seleccionar) con expresiones regulares?

Tags: regex

recurro a la sabiduría de esta comunidad, con expresión regular necesito obtener los  que NO cumplen: `99.*\.(xxx|yyy|zzz)@test.com`

Grupo:
99.xxx@test.com
990.yyy@test.com
991.zyz@test.com
991.aaa@test.com
995871.abcdefg@test.com

Obtener:
991.zyz@test.com
991.aaa@test.com
995871.abcdefg@test.com

Entiendo que hay negar, pero no doy con la tecla.

Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: te recomiendo hacer validaciones positivas en vez de validaciones negativas, la expresión regular negada va a aceptar muchas cosas que posiblemente no quieras como por ejemplo emojis

Comment: Si vas a usar el regex en un lenguaje de programación, puedes negar el regex por fuera. Por ejemplo en Python sería if(not re.fullmatch(regex))

Answer (score 1):

Para algo así puedes usar el **look ahead** negativo, es decir, buscar lo siguiente que **no** coincida con la expresión dada.

La documentación (MDN) la puedes ver [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#other_assertions)

```
re = /^(?!(99.*\.(xxx|yyy|zzz)@test.com))/

re.test('99.xxx@test.com') // false
re.test('991.zyz@test.com') // true
```

La expresión basicamente dice: El inicio de la línea no está seguido de *(99.*.(xxx|yyy|zzz)@test.com)*

La otra alternativa es simplemente dejar tu expresión de forma positiva (como ya la tienes) y descartar los resultados que sí coincidan con el patrón.

```
re = /99.*\.(xxx|yyy|zzz)@test.com/

!re.test('99.xxx@test.com') // false
!re.test('991.zyz@test.com') // true
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos.